# difference between find() and where() in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Can anybody describe what is the difference between `find()` and `where()` in `Laravel`.

Sometimes it's showing the same results but sometimes is showing error.

Answer (score 4):

The `where()` methods gets translated to a `WHERE` of the underlying RDBMS (like MySQL, Postgres) and you use this to find records by one or more constraints (color, size). It returns always a `Builder` instance.

The `find()` method is a special *where*, which used to find a record by its primary ID. It returns an instance of the Eloquent model or a collection (in case you passing multiple IDs to the method) or `null` (in case no result was found).